# Write the expression in terms of $\log x$ and $\log y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> $$\log\Big(\frac{x^3}{10y}\Big)$$
>   Write the above expression in terms of $\log x$ and $\log y$.

To be honest, I'm really unsure as to how the final answer should look like. In other words, what is the question asking for, and how do I go about getting there?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It probably wants to see something like $a\log x+ b\log y+c$.

Comment: @AlexR Yes, you're right. EDIT: Corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\log\left(\frac{x^3}{10y}\right) =\log\left(x^3\right)-\log\left(10\cdot y\right) $$ You can use additional properties of logarithms until you get $\log x$ and $\log y$ to appear in your answer. You will need one application each of the properties $$\log\left(a^n\right) = n\log\left(a\right) \\ \log\left(ab\right) = \log\left(a\right)+\log\left(b\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, that really helps. So now I have 3logx - log10y. How do I move the y now? Or do I need to?

Comment: @MM98 Use $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$ again and you're done. Note that we use MathJax here, cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: You can move the $y$ out by using the second property I noted

Comment: Fantastic. Thank-you very much.

Comment: For sure! Glad my answer worked.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\log\left(\frac{x^3}{10y}\right) =3\log x-\log 10-\log y
$$
If $\log=\log_{10}$, then $\log 10=1$.